# What is the best frame work for a card game to make for an iPhone?

Tags: ios

I was looking through all the options ,but I can't decide. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any open source code card game for Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274235/any-open-source-code-card-game-for-xcode) Please to not repost questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review the most excellent website managed by [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com). There are wonderful contributors such as [Matthjis Hollemans](http://twitter.com/#!/mhollemans) who produced the epic [How To Make a Simple Playing Card Game with Multiplayer and Bluetooth](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1).